# How to fix error with AWS Lambda handler, DynamoDB Put req?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, put

Trying to create a Lambda to interact with my DynamoDB.
This specific Lambda is to put/write an item to the DB:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
)

type Item struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Rname    string `json:"rname"`
}

func Put() error {

    // Create a session - London Region
    session, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-west-2")},
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    svc := dynamodb.New(session)

    // Create instance of Item Struct
    item := Item{
        Email:    "123@mail.com",
        Password: "12345678",
        Rname:    "abcde",
    }

    // Marshall Item
    av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error marshalling map:")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Create Item
    input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      av,
        TableName: aws.String("accountsTable"),
    }

    _, err = svc.PutItem(input)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error calling PutItem:")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Put())
}
```

However getting the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "handler is nil",
  "errorType": "errorString"
}
```

I have changed the handler in run time settings to main too so don't think that would be the issue.

Building with:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a main.go
```

and putting the zip of the executable into AWS via console (no IAC's)

Any help would be greatly appreciated to resolve this error! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to execute an empty Lambda function without the logic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, just like a simple hello world to print?

Comment: Exactly, just to rule out if the error is from the function setup or from custom logic.

Comment: just tried and got a failure just trying to print out hello, the function that main calls returning the same hello string. Fails on "handler kind string is not func"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass function handle not function result to `lambda.Start`

Please update your main function with

```
func main() {
    lambda.Start(Put)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - just realised this before I came back to here! Silly one to be stuck on for so long haha